# Scala spark, input dataframe, return columns where all values equal to 1

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, filter, apache-spark-sql

Given a dataframe, say that it contains 4 columns and 3 rows. I want to write a function to return the columns where all the values in that column are equal to 1.

This is a Scala code. I want to use some spark transformations to transform or filter the dataframe input. This filter should be implemented in a function.

```
case class Grade(c1: Integral, c2: Integral, c3: Integral, c4: Integral)
val example = Seq(
      Grade(1,3,1,1),
      Grade(1,1,null,1),
      Grade(1,10,2,1)
    )

    val dfInput = spark.createDataFrame(example)
```

After I call the function filterColumns()

```
val dfOutput = dfInput.filterColumns()
```

it should return 3 row 2 columns dataframe with value all 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more readable approach using `Dataset[Grade]`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import scala.collection.mutable
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

val tmp = dfInput.map(grade => grade.dropWhenNotEqualsTo(1))
val rowsCount = dfInput.count()

val colsToRetain = mutable.Set[Column]()
 for (column <- tmp.columns) {
   val withoutNullsCount = tmp.select(column).na.drop().count()
   if (rowsCount == withoutNullsCount) colsToRetain += col(column)
}

dfInput.select(colsToRetain.toArray:_*).show()

+---+---+
| c4| c1|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  1|  1|
|  1|  1|
+---+---+
```

And the case object

```
case class Grade(c1: Integer, c2: Integer, c3: Integer, c4: Integer) {
  def dropWhenNotEqualsTo(n: Integer): Grade = {
    Grade(nullOrValue(c1, n), nullOrValue(c2, n), nullOrValue(c3, n), nullOrValue(c4, n))
  }
  def nullOrValue(c: Integer, n: Integer) = if (c == n) c else null
}
```

1. `grade.dropWhenNotEqualsTo(1)` -> returns a new Grade with values that not satisfies the condition replaced to nulls

```
+---+----+----+---+
| c1|  c2|  c3| c4|
+---+----+----+---+
|  1|null|   1|  1|
|  1|   1|null|  1|
|  1|null|null|  1|
+---+----+----+---+
```

2. `(column <- tmp.columns)`  -> iterate over the columns
3. `tmp.select(column).na.drop()` -> drop rows with nulls
   e.g for `c2` this will return

```
+---+
| c2|
+---+
|  1|
+---+
```

4. `if (rowsCount == withoutNullsCount) colsToRetain += col(column)` -> if column contains nulls just drop it

Comment: Can you tell me what packages I need to import? And, colsToRetain += col(column) has some error, can you kindly explain "col()" and "+=", it shows error in my computer.

Comment: `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col`, `import scala.collection.mutable`, `import org.apache.spark.sql.Column` should be enough

Comment: Thank you. The map function require encoder? what does that mean? And can you change the output dataframe the same order as input? Say c1,c4, not c4, c1

Comment: about encoders - https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-Encoder.html they are available as implicit conversions from `import sparkSession.implicits._` To preserve order use `List` instead of `Set`

Answer (score 1):

one of the options is `reduce` on rdd:

```
  import spark.implicits._

  val df= Seq(("1","A","3","4"),("1","2","?","4"),("1","2","3","4")).toDF()
  df.show()

  val first = df.first()
  val size = first.length
  val diffStr = "#"
  val targetStr = "1"

   def rowToArray(row: Row): Array[String] = {
     val arr = new Array[String](row.length)
     for (i <- 0 to row.length-1){
       arr(i) = row.getString(i)
     }
     arr
   }

  def compareArrays(a1: Array[String], a2: Array[String]): Array[String] = {
    val arr = new Array[String](a1.length)
    for (i <- 0 to a1.length-1){
      arr(i) = if (a1(i).equals(a2(i)) && a1(i).equals(targetStr)) a1(i) else diffStr
    }
    arr
  }

  val diff = df.rdd
    .map(rowToArray)
    .reduce(compareArrays)

  val cols = (df.columns zip diff).filter(!_._2.equals(diffStr)).map(s=>df(s._1))

  df.select(cols:_*).show()
```

```
    +---+---+---+---+
    | _1| _2| _3| _4|
    +---+---+---+---+
    |  1|  A|  3|  4|
    |  1|  2|  ?|  4|
    |  1|  2|  3|  4|
    +---+---+---+---+

    +---+
    | _1|
    +---+
    |  1|
    |  1|
    |  1|
    +---+
```

Comment: Can you kindly explain the last two lines? Thank you.

Comment: zip creates list of tuples where ._1 element is column name and ._2 from `diff`, `(_1,1)
(_2,#)
(_3,#)
(_4,#)`, then I filtered out records with '#' and return only column name in map step. Finally I put these column names into select as varargs using :_*

Answer (score 1):

I would try to prepare dataset for processing without `null`s. In case of few columns this simple iterative approach might work fine (don't forget to import spark implicits before `import spark.implicits._`):

```
val example = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    Grade(1,3,1,1),
    Grade(1,1,0,1),
    Grade(1,10,2,1)
)).toDS().cache()

def allOnes(colName: String, ds: Dataset[Grade]): Boolean = {
    val row = ds.select(colName).distinct().collect()
    if (row.length == 1 && row.head.getInt(0) == 1) true
    else false
}

val resultColumns = example.columns.filter(col => allOnes(col, example))
example.selectExpr(resultColumns: _*).show()
```

result is:

```
+---+---+
| c1| c4|
+---+---+
|  1|  1|
|  1|  1|
|  1|  1|
+---+---+
```

If `null`s are inevitable, use untyped dataset (aka dataframe):

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(
    StructField("c1", IntegerType, nullable = true),
    StructField("c2", IntegerType, nullable = true),
    StructField("c3", IntegerType, nullable = true),
    StructField("c4", IntegerType, nullable = true)
))

val example = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    Row(1,3,1,1),
    Row(1,1,null,1),
    Row(1,10,2,1)
))

val dfInput = spark.createDataFrame(example, schema).cache()

def allOnes(colName: String, df: DataFrame): Boolean = {
    val row = df.select(colName).distinct().collect()
    if (row.length == 1 && row.head.getInt(0) == 1) true
    else false
}

val resultColumns= dfInput.columns.filter(col => allOnes(col, dfInput))
dfInput.selectExpr(resultColumns: _*).show()
```